# Link a bubble in Bubble Picker with a button

Tags: java, android, button

I use Bubble Picker library. I want to be able to link each bubble in my Bubble Picker (I have 10) with one Button that will go another of 10 activities.

I guess you have to add some code to OnBubbleSelected.

P.S. I'm new at coding, so it's hard for me to do so. I'll be grateful for your answers

```
public class Main777Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    BubblePicker picker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main777);

        final String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hashtags);
        final TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.colors);

        picker = findViewById(R.id.picker);
        picker.setAdapter(new BubblePickerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getTotalCount() {
                return titles.length;
            }

            @NotNull
            @Override
            public PickerItem getItem(int position) {
                PickerItem item = new PickerItem();
                item.setTitle(titles[position]);
                item.setGradient(new BubbleGradient(colors.getColor((position * 2) % 8, 0),
                        colors.getColor((position * 2) % 8 + 1, 0), BubbleGradient.VERTICAL));
                item.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Main777Activity.this, android.R.color.white));
                return item;
            }



        });


        picker.setBubbleSize(45);
        picker.setSwipeMoveSpeed(2f);
        picker.setAlwaysSelected(false);
        picker.setMaxSelectedCount( 1 );



        picker.setListener(new BubblePickerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBubbleSelected(@NotNull PickerItem item) {
                picker.getSelectedItems();
                picker.setListener(this);

            }

            @Override
            public void onBubbleDeselected(@NotNull PickerItem item) {

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        picker.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        picker.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide some examples of how to code executes currently and its output? Providing the desired and current output will help make the ask clear. If there is an error please add its stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow community

Now you want to start a different activity for each selected bubble item; please correct me if I am wrong.

To do that you need to start your activity intent within `onBubbleSelected()` of `BubblePickerListener` of the `BubblePicker` widget, and utilize the `item` argument to differentiate between items; you can use `item.getTitle()` for that

To to so:

```
picker.setListener(new BubblePickerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBubbleSelected(@NotNull PickerItem item) {

        if (item.getTitle() != null) {
            switch(item.getTitle()) {

                case "item1":
                    // start activity of item1 
                    break;

                case "item2":
                    // start activity of item2
                    break;

                case "item3":
                    // start activity of item3
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBubbleDeselected(@NotNull PickerItem item) {

    }
});
```

And below is the full example semplified with a single activity for all items, but passing in a different value (item title) for each item.

**How it looks like**

[image]

**Layout**

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.igalata.bubblepicker.rendering.BubblePicker
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:backgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_planet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PlanetActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Behavior**

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BubblePicker picker = findViewById(R.id.picker);
        picker.setBubbleSize(10);


        final String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
        final TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.colors);

        picker.setAdapter(new BubblePickerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getTotalCount() {
                return titles.length;
            }

            @NotNull
            @Override
            public PickerItem getItem(int position) {
                PickerItem item = new PickerItem();
                item.setTitle(titles[position]);
                item.setTextSize(80);
                item.setColor(colors.getColor(position, 0));

                item.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, android.R.color.white));
                return item;
            }
        });


        picker.setListener(new BubblePickerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBubbleSelected(@NotNull PickerItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlanetActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("planet", item.getTitle());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBubbleDeselected(@NotNull PickerItem item) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

PlanetActivity

```
public class PlanetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_planet);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("planet"));

    }
}
```

**Resources**

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">BubblePickerLibrary</string>
    <string name="earth">Earth</string>
    <string name="moon">Moon</string>
    <string name="jupiter">Jupiter</string>
    <string name="mercury">Mercury</string>
    <string name="venus">Venus</string>
    <string name="mars">Mars</string>
    <string name="saturn">Saturn</string>
    <string name="uranus">Uranus</string>
    <string name="neptune">Neptune</string>


    <string-array name="planets">
        <item>@string/earth</item>
        <item>@string/moon</item>
        <item>@string/mercury</item>
        <item>@string/venus</item>
        <item>@string/mars</item>
        <item>@string/saturn</item>
        <item>@string/uranus</item>
        <item>@string/neptune</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="earth">#ffe3e9</color>
    <color name="moon">#ffd014</color>
    <color name="mercury">#009999</color>
    <color name="venus">#990000</color>
    <color name="mars">#808080</color>
    <color name="saturn">#ff00ff</color>
    <color name="uranus">#800080</color>
    <color name="neptune">#00ffff</color>


    <string-array name="colors">
        <item>@color/earth</item>
        <item>@color/moon</item>
        <item>@color/mercury</item>
        <item>@color/venus</item>
        <item>@color/mars</item>
        <item>@color/saturn</item>
        <item>@color/uranus</item>
        <item>@color/neptune</item>
    </string-array>


</resources>
```

**Dependencies**

App Module level

```
implementation 'com.github.igalata:Bubble-Picker:v0.2.4'
```

Project Level

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```